# JOIN Multiple Tables with Many to Many Relationship

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I have around 30 tables. eg: producer, director etc related to movies

each table consists of movie_id and celeb_id field

there is a table celebs which consists of fields: celeb_id celeb_name

For a specific movie_id i want all the information retrieved in a single query.

```
SELECT b_movies.*, bb_celebs.celeb_name 
FROM b_movies
LEFT JOIN b_producer ON b_movies.id = b_producer.movie_id 
LEFT JOIN bb_celebs ON b_producer.celeb_id = bb_celebs.celeb_id
LEFT JOIN b_director ON b_movies.id = b_director.movie_id 
LEFT JOIN bb_celebs ON b_director.celeb_id = bb_celebs.celeb_id
WHERE b_movies.id = 'UNIQUE ID';
```

I want the names of celebs associated with the type of work:

```
Director
1. ABC
2. XYZ

Producer
1. ABC2
2. XYZ2
```

All names of celebs are stored in celebs table with celeb_id and celeb_name
and in producer table movie_id and celeb_id and same structure applies to directors, etc.. all other tables

Please help.

Regards,

Kenh

Comment: Horrible database design. You should have a `Person` table and a `Role` table (e.g., producer, director, celebrity, etc.) and a junction table `Person_Movie_Role` to link the three entities together.

Comment: @Joe if i follow the design as suggested by you, In future won't it be bulky when there are many movies and querying through large no of rows in the Person_Movie_Role Table might consume a lot of time

Comment: Ken - this is what databases are designed for-  handling large amounts of data :)

Comment: @Kenh: With proper indexing, the joins required should not be a problem.

Comment: @freddie Yup! I guess joe and you are right. will redo the design. Thanks!

Comment: @Joe Are you sure even if we use indexes, cardinality might be huge in future for persons and movies. You seem to be more experienced. If you say it will be fine, I will go with it.

Comment: @Kenh: One of my cardinal rules for database design is "Don't assume performance problems before you have them." I have a very similar arrangement in a production system. 650K rows in our "Movie" table. 1.7M rows in our "Person" table. No problems at all.

Comment: @Joe: Thanks a lot! That gives me lot of confidence.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

(select 'Director', celeb.name from celebs c join director d on c.celeb_id = d.celeb_id and d.movie_id = "movie_id")

union all

(select 'Producer', celeb.name from celebs c join producer p on c.celeb_id = p.celeb_id and p.movie_id = "movie_id")

union all
.....

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
LEFT JOIN ... ON ...
WHERE ...
ORDER BY ...
```

Appropriate values for `...` are left as an excercise to the OP...

Comment: i tried left join but it results in duplicate column names error as i need celeb_names related to a movie ordered by profession.

Comment: Read up one SQL join syntax. if you have the same field name in multiple tables and you're needing them in the same query, you have to use `tablename.fieldname` to distinguish WHICH table/field combo you're referring to.

Comment: SELECT b_movies.*, bb_celebs.celeb_name 
FROM b_movies
LEFT INNER JOIN b_producer ON b_movies.id = b_producer.movie_id 
LEFT INNER JOIN bb_celebs ON b_producer.celeb_id = bb_celebs.celeb_id
LEFT INNER JOIN b_director ON b_movies.id = b_director.movie_id 
LEFT INNER JOIN bb_celebs ON b_director.celeb_id = bb_celebs.celeb_id
WHERE b_movies.id = 'UNIQUE ID';

I want the names of celebs associated with the type of work:

Director
1. ABC
2. XYZ

Producer
1. ABC2
2. XYZ2

All names of celebs are stored in celebs table with celeb_id and celeb_name
producer table has movie_id and celeb_id

Comment: *sorry its not LEFT INNER JOIN ITS ONLY LEFT JOIN